# attachment displaying full path when emailed using perl script

Tags: perl

My perl script emails attachment which displays full path (/abc/xyz/report.xls) in outlook email client but not in lotus notes email client.

environment: 2010 Outlook on windows 7 OS.

How do I make sure path is not displayed in the attachment?

**Code Snippet:**

```
&sendEmail(@subject, @message, $exception_report_xls);

sub sendEmail
{
        my $subject = "@subject";
        my $distlist = 'ayc@abc.com';
        my $message ="\n\n\n@message \n";

        my $send = system("\(echo \"$message\" ; uuencode \"$exception_report_xls\"   \"$exception_report_xls\"\) |  mailx -s \"$subject\" \"$distlist\"");

}
```

Appreciate any resonse!

Ramya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing the full path and filename of the XLS file in the source of the message.  So, some mail clients will display the full path.

If you are wedded to using (antiquated) UUENCODE, try it this way instead:

```
        sub Send_Email_UUENCODE {
          local($to, $from, $subj, $message, $attach) = @_;
          local($i,$filename,$cmd,$att,$mailprog);


          $i=length($attach)-1;
          while( (substr($attach,$i,1) cmp '/')!=0 && $i>0) {$i--;}
          $filename=substr($attach,$i+1,length($attach)-$i-1);  


            if ($attach) {
               $cmd="uuencode " . $attach . ' ' . $filename;
               $att=`$cmd`;
            }
            $mailprog = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -f " . $from; 
            open (MAIL, "|$mailprog $to") || die "Can't open $mailprog!\n";
            print MAIL "To: $to\n";
            print MAIL "From: $from\n";
            print MAIL "Subject: $subj\n";
            print MAIL "$message\n";

            if ($attach) {
              print MAIL "$att\n";
            }
            close (MAIL);
        }
```

But, better might be to use MIME encoding instead of UUENCODE.

Comment: Thanks mti2935! I removed full path and filename of the XLS file in the source of the message and made some changes in calling sub. Working as expected.